# Getting derived class objects out of a vector<Parent*>

Tags: c++

I know that you can store a bunch of Parent* objects in a vector. However, if the functions you need to call on the objects cannot be defined in the parent class (they depend on a template parameter of the subclass) then how are you supposed to retrieve the objects from the container?

In this example:

```
#include <iostream>

class ImageBase{};

template <typename TPixel>
class Image : public ImageBase
{
public:
  TPixel GetPixel() const {TPixel a; return a;}
};

template<typename TImage>
void Output(const TImage* image)
{
  std::cout << image->GetPixel();
}

int main(int, char *[])
{
  // Works correctly
  {
  Image<float>* image = new Image<float>;
  image->GetPixel();
  Output(image);
  }

  {
  ImageBase* image = new Image<float>;
  Output(image);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The Output(image); where 'image' is a ImageBase* fails (of course) because GetPixel is not defined in ImageBase. I know you can dynamic_cast<> to a bunch of types to figure out if the subclass matches any of them, but this list could very quickly get very long. The long list would be fine if it could reside in one place, but how would you make a function to do this? The function would take an ImageBase*, but what would it return?

```
returnType? GetSubclass(ImageBase* input)
{
  if(dynamic_cast<Image<float>*>(input))
    {
    return Image<float>*;
    }
  else if(dynamic_cast<Image<int>*>(input))
    {
    return Image<int>*;
    }
}
```

It seems reasonable to me to want to be able to call some template functions on subclasses that only vary in signature by their template parameter (as setup in this example), does it not?

In my real case, both Image and ImageBase are part of a library, so I cannot change them.

Comment: check out the visitor design pattern, this allows you to implement double dispatch.

Comment: Try Boost.any perhaps, which as an `any_cast` function.

Comment: Kerrek SB - for any_cast you already need to know the type, right?
std::vector<boost::any> v;
v.push_back(new int);
int* any_cast<int> (v[0]);

Comment: p3trus - I thought the idea of double dispatch was "dispatches a function call to different concrete functions depending on the runtime types of two objects involved in the call". Here I only have one object, right?

Comment: @David: The two objects are the `Image` and the image-processing algorithm.

Comment: I will suggest that a container of pointers-to-base is the wrong solution here (it sounds like you're violating the [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).

Comment: @Ben Voigt So I will still end up with a giant list of types, Visit(Image<float>), Visit(Image<int>), etc, etc right? And also the free functions I need to call aren't classes (so they don't form a hierarchy) so I still don't see how Visitor applies?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth - I'm happy to do something different - can you suggest what? haha

Comment: It's simple you pass a visitor to the ImageBase. The accepting member function is virtual. So you end in the Image::accept function. There you know you're an Image. If you then call the visit function of your visitor you can send your real type.

Comment: @David: Well, that's kind of up to you, really.  If you want to access pixels, why are you storing a vector of pointers to a class that doesn't support that functionality?  An alternative question is: why does your `ImageBase` not support a `getPixel()` function?

Comment: There are a lot of variations of the visitor pattern. If you've got a lot of types check out the acyclic visitor pattern.

Comment: @DavidDoria: Yes, you have a giant list of types.  But you said "The long list would be fine if it could reside in one place".  Please have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: @Oli Charsworth - ImageBase cannot support getPixel because the return type if TPixel which ImageBase does not know about.

Comment: @P3trus - If I do this: http://ideone.com/dvq8r then I have to have a separate visitor for every function I want to call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visitor pattern to recover the type information, possibly with a templated helper implementing the `visit` function.

First, let's make your algorithm into a polymorphic functor object:

```
struct Output
{
    std::ostream& dest;
    Output(std::ostream& destination) : dest(destination) {}

    template<typename PixelType>
    void operator()(const Image<PixelType>* image) const
    {
        dest << image->GetPixel();
    }
};
```

Now, let's add a visitor interface:

```
struct ImageVisitor /* abstract */
{
    virtual void Visit(Image<RGBQUAD>*) const = 0;
    virtual void Visit(Image<RGBTRIPLE>*) const = 0;
    virtual void Visit(Image<RGBQUAD16>*) const = 0;
    virtual void Visit(Image<RGBTRIPLE16>*) const = 0;
    virtual void Visit(Image<RGBQUADF>*) const = 0;
    virtual void Visit(Image<RGBTRIPLEF>*) const = 0;
    virtual void Visit(Image<RGBQUADD>*) const = 0;
    virtual void Visit(Image<RGBTRIPLED>*) const = 0;
};
```

And a forwarder:

```
template<typename Functor>
struct ImageVisitorShim : ImageVisitor
{
    Functor& fn;
    ImageVisitorShim(Functor& algorithm) : fn(algorithm) {}

    virtual void Visit(Image<RGBQUAD>     *im) const { fn(im); }
    virtual void Visit(Image<RGBTRIPLE>   *im) const { fn(im); }
    virtual void Visit(Image<RGBQUAD16>   *im) const { fn(im); }
    virtual void Visit(Image<RGBTRIPLE16> *im) const { fn(im); }
    virtual void Visit(Image<RGBQUADF>    *im) const { fn(im); }
    virtual void Visit(Image<RGBTRIPLEF>  *im) const { fn(im); }
    virtual void Visit(Image<RGBQUADD>    *im) const { fn(im); }
    virtual void Visit(Image<RGBTRIPLED>  *im) const { fn(im); }
};
```

And a factory:

```
template<typename Functor>
ImageVisitorShim<Functor> MakeImageVisitor(Functor& f) { return f; }
```

Now a visitor-compliant image wrapper:

```
struct VisitableImageBase
{
    virtual void VisitWith(const ImageVisitor&) = 0;
};

template<typename PixelType>
struct VisitableImage : VisitableImageBase
{
    unique_ptr<Image<PixelType>> content; // or shared or raw pointer, if ownership is elsewhere

    VisitableImage(Image<PixelType>* im) : content(im) {}

    virtual void VisitWith(const ImageVisitor& v) { v.Visit(content.get()); }
};
```

Finally, you are able to use a polymorphic vector of images!

```
vector<unique_ptr<VisitableImageBase>> images;
Output outputter(std::cout);
for( auto vim : images ) vim->VisitWith(MakeImageVisitor(outputter));
```

That was a lot of code, but the good thing is that new types can be added without affecting existing functors (just extend the shim) as long as the functor was implemented with a template.  And not much code is needed to add more image processing functions (just a new template functor class, similar to `Output`).

Comment: Hm, I am aware of the Visitor pattern, but I don't see how it applies here. I've seen it in the context of performing an operation on every item in a container, but in this case, performing that operation is exactly where I am having trouble. Would I have to use the visitor in all of the functions I want to call with these objects?

Comment: Ben Voigt - wow, that IS a lot of code. Thanks for the example! However, I have tons of function templates that would be very tedious to turn into Functors. I still don't really understand why this is so complicated. The subclass objects still "know" their type right - I don't see why there isn't a function that can get them back to their original type? (created by 'new')

Comment: Ben Voigt - does it become significantly easier if I could edit ImageBase? I suppose I could create my own parent class : class MyImageBase : public ImageBase and do whatever I want there.

Comment: @DavidDoria: In some future version of C++, you'll be able to trivially convert a function template to a polymorphic functor using lambdas.  But polymorphic lambdas didn't make it into C++11.  Having a function that can get the original type back is easy (`#include <typeinfo>`), but as you mentioned in your question, the problem is that you need the original type at compile-time, not run-time, so you can use it for return values, local variables, overload resolution, etc.  And then you need run-time selection from all those compile-time variants.

Comment: @DavidDoria: Do note, however, that the polymorphic functor `operator()()` can call all the function templates it wants, and the right thing will happen.